# Google Maps API - Getting fastest route with multiple way points

Tags: maps

I have been reviewing the Google maps API, (specifically the Directions API), and in theory I know what I want but am having trouble finding the documentation for it;

I have a set of addresses that I would like the fastest route for;

maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=START_ADDRESS&destination=###1###&waypoints=###2###,###3###,###ETC###&key=MY_API_KEY

I have surrounded the params I will explain below with ###;

1; This is unknown as I want the furthest address to be the last point; At the moment this is done by getting all of the times distance and just doing it that way, but If I have 3 addresses and address 2 is closer than address 3, but its quicker to go to address 1 then address 3 then address 2 last then it's not good.

2&3; Google seems to just go through the addresses in the order I put them here, and what I actually want is to go in order of the fastest route, the order of addresses does not actually indicate this.

Just wondering what approach I could take, is there something I have missed in the API,

Thanks in advance,

Robert

**NB: If something isn't clear please comment and I will try to clarify.**

Answer (score 0):

Found out there is an optimise parameter for way-points!:

`maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=x&destination=x&waypoints=optimise:true|y|z&key=MY_API_KEY`